# Ipython is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, ipython

I installed Ipython with using :

> pip install ipython

And here is the code that I want make it to work :

> from Ipython.display import Audio

But it gives an error : "No module named Ipython.display". How can I fix the problem ? I am using python2.7 on ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IPython` unfortunately does not follow the popular Python naming convention. The first two letters are in uppercase:

```
from IPython.display import Audio
```